# Getting error "No route to host" for JangoSmtp Cakephp config

Tags: cakephp, routes, smtp

Here is my Code:

```
    function sendMail($template = null, $to_email = null, $from_email = null,
   $subject = null,  $contents = array()) {
$this->Email->to  = $to_email;
$this->Email->subject = $subject;
$this->Email->from =$from_email;
$this->Email->template = $template;
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';

$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
    'timeout'=>'30',
    'port' => '25',
    'host' => 'relay.jangosmtp.net',
    'username' => 'users',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'transport' => 'Smtp',
    'tls' => true
);
$this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';


    $this->set('contents', $content);
    $this->Email->send();
```

}

I am getting error as "No route to host"  can anybody help me out to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

"No route to host" indicates that this is not an issue of the script but more likely the configuration of your mail server.

https://www.google.com/search?q=smtp+No+route+to+host